# Ui design and development in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, user-interface, java-me

I need to create a Blackberry User interface which looks like the given image, where **?** is an image,

[image]

I tried a lot to design this UI but could not succeed.
Can anybody help me to design this UI?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

You'll definitely need to implement your own custom Manager that does the layout for the fields, as well as implementing the focus, navigation, and touch functionality. Your best bet is to simply make squares out of each segment, and then lay them out sort of overlapping one another. 
[image: overlapping example]

After that override the navigation and focus methods for trackpad use to move the selection around. As far as touch events you should convert the (x,y) into polar coordinates for ease of detecting which segment you're touching, rather than just seeing which field is layed out under the given point, as you will have multiple.

Here's a link that you may find useful: [How to - Create a custom layout manager for a screen](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800508/How_To_-_Create_a_custom_layout_manager_for_a_screen.html?nodeid=800263&vernum=0)

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: +1. A nice info to start with. I would also add you'll most likely need several image sets for this UI because there various screen dimentions on the market.

Comment: sir: Actually am very new to blackberry Ui. can u plz send me a small snippet of code that help me to go forward

Comment: @khushi I've edited the answer to include a link to a How to article

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [CustomItem](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/javax/microedition/lcdui/CustomItem.html) that allows you draw directly on Canvas, but in same time it does provide you with number of listeners that can be easily linked to items(areas) from Canvas